# Permission denied while making directory kivymd, python

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy, buildozer

I want to create directory in primary_external_storage_path() but while running buildozer android debug deploy run logcat it says PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I have done necessary lines
`import os
from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path

request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])`

I also added permissions in buildozer.spec

checking if permission is granted returns True

I try to make folder with this code
`path = primary_external_storage_path() Folder = 'example' dire = os.path.join(path, Folder) os.mkdir(dire)`

Comment: Using an Android 11+ device?

Comment: Yes, android 11

Comment: Well you have no access to root of external storage then. Use an existing public directory on external storage (like Documents, Download, Pictures, DCIM,...) to create your subdirs and files.